# Additive characters of Quotient ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $K$ is finite Galois extension of rationals, and let $\mathcal O$ be the ring of integers of $K$,
and finally suppose $\mathfrak m$ is an integral ideal of $\mathcal O$,
I want to classify additive characters of the group $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$.

There is a definition involving the notion of different ideal but is somewhat obscruing...

Regards.